# Получить исходник HTML-страницы в сыром виде (из расширения Chrome)

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

К примеру, есть страничка `BadHTML.html`, которая не отличается корректностью: нету закрывающих тегов, нету кавычек и т.д.:

```
<body>
<table border=10><form method=post>
<tr><td><input type="text" name="shit" value="value">
<tr><td><input type="submit">
```

Если такую страничку загрузить в браузер и спросить `document.body.outerHTML`, то результат будет "исправлен":

```
<table border="10"><form method="post"></form>
<tbody><tr><td><input type="text" name="shit" value="value">
</td></tr><tr><td><input type="submit">
</td></tr></tbody></table></body>
```

Мне же нужно найти способ получения оригинала страницы. Можно через webRequest получить тело страницы, но это нужно будет перезагружать страничку. Хотелось бы найти способ получать исходник именно уже открытой страницы.

Comment: Всякие расширения, такие как https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/view-current-source/bloebkffnmchginelkmdcemamcdeamei/related?hl=en якобы показывают исходник, а на самом деле показывают уже обработанный и "исправленный" DOM

Comment: то что "уже загружено" вы не получите - это уже обработал браузер (в частности "исправил" формат, выполнил скрипты и т.п.). А зачем оно вообще надо?

Comment: Можно использовать прокси типа Burp Suit. Он будет между между сервером и браузером принимать то, что отдаёт сервер. Это для пентеста используют, но можно попробовать и для вот такого. Либо же просто написать на ноде/го (ну просто потому что быстро и не сложно) самому тулзу, которая будет писать в файл ответ от сервера как он есть. А открытой именно страницы из браузера не, не знаю варианта. Браузер некорректный хтмл правит сам.

Comment: Прокси использовать сложно, так как https, а возиться с сертификатами лень (тогда уж stripssl). Вот и подумалось, что можно малой кровью прямо из браузера вытаскивать сорсы интересных страничек и отправлять на локалхост для дальнейшего анализа. Так как все равно писать своего демона, то может быть и до проксей с подменой сертификатов дойду, но это пока не точно, все равно функциональность браузера нужна, скрипты на чем-то запускать надо.